# Checking inputs against each other jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to check a users input against their in-putted email to check if they are too similar, if they are I need to throw an error. For example;

"The user name can’t be too similar to the email address e.g. if the email address is charlie@hud.ac.uk the username can’t be charlie."

How could I go about doing this?

EDIT: I want to check the username against the first section of the email address, the section before the @

Comment: Firstly you'll have to define for yourself what exactly "too similar" means. Once you know that it will just be an issue of implementing those conditions. You'll have to be a bit more specific in order to get some concrete answers.

Comment: This condition still allows for similar username's emails.  `bob` will be allowed for `bob1@email.com`. You might want to think about these scenarios as well.

Comment: This piece of work is for a uni assignment and they only test against if the whole thing is similar, not sections. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var email, username;
if (username === email.split('@')[0]) {
  alert('failed');
}
```

This will compare the username with the username part of email.

***Edit:***
The point is you could get the username part from the email by `email.split('@')[0]`, then how similar is defined by you.

```
function is_similar (str1, str2) {
    // implement your similar logic here
    // return true or false
}
```

Comment: if the username is `bob` and the email is `bob1@gmail.com` this test won't be too effective.

Comment: @Lix From the example from the op, this fill the requirement.

Comment: I won't argue about assumptions made regarding the conditions. The question clearly sates `"can’t be too similar"`. You are however searching only for an exact match.

Comment: @Lix Anyway, only op know what he wants, I just give one solution. If this is not what he wants, I'll delete the answer :)

Comment: Was just making a dummy edit to remove my vote - looks like you were correct.

Comment: @Lix Yep, your comment is nice, the question is not clear at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkUsernameAndEmail(){

    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
    // check to see if the email contains the username in anypart
    if(email.split("@")[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(user.toLowerCase() ) > -1){
      alert("Email address cannot contain the username");
      return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to expand here on the existing answers. You said this is for an assignment, but this requirement is seen in many applications - answers here will will still be useful to users implementing this feature in production.

Defining what you consider "similar" is the first thing to do. For example, upper/lower cases. Is `bob` too similar to `BoB`? In my opinion it is. So the first thing we will want to do is convert all strings into the same case. In JavaScript you have [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase). You might also decide that certain symbols don't change the string enough and therefore will want to ignore them. For example, `bob` is pretty similar to `b.ob`. For such cases you might want to remove those "meaningless" symbols. With JavaScript, for this purpose you could use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Defining the laws has to come before implementing the conditions.

A final note to make here is that you are performing client side validation. Any validation done in JavaScript can be easily bypassed if the user disables JavaScript or alters the code on the page. Validation of this sort should **always** be done on the server. You can leave the client side validation there to improve the user experience and also not to send requests to the server that are clearly invalid.